# Создание окна toplevel при определенном условии

Tags: python, tkinter, telegram, telethon

Пишу простенький спамер для телеграмм. Решил сделать графический интерфейс.
Нужно чтобы если сессия логина не была сохранена то открывалось окно с вводом номера телефона и кода подтверждения. Подскажите как это возможно реализовать?

```
from tkinter import *
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events
from time import sleep
import random

from telethon.errors import PeerFloodError
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import SendMessageRequest
def login():
   api_id=(entry1.get())
   api_hash=(entry2.get())
   phone=(entry3.get())
   client = TelegramClient('Spam-session', api_id, api_hash)
   client.start()
   client.connect()
   client.flood_sleep_threshold = 0
   if not  client.is_user_authorized():
      def login2():
         log2 = Toplevel()
         log2.geometry('250x250')


         client.send_code_request(phone)
         client.sign_in(phone, input('Введите полученный код: '))

root=Tk()
root.title('TG Spamer')
root.geometry('800x600')
#entry block
entry1=Entry(root, width=15)
entry2=Entry(root, width=50)
entry3=Entry(root, width=15)
#label block
label1=Label(root,text='Введите api id')
label2=Label(root,text='Введите hash api')
label3=Label(root,text='Введите номер телефона')
#button block
button1=Button(root,text=u'Вторая кнопка')
button1.config(command=login)
#button block
button1.place(x=500, y=500)
#label block
label1.place(x=100,y=50)
label2.place(x=100,y=100)
label3.place(x=100,y=150)
#entry block
entry1.place(x=300,y=50)
entry2.place(x=300,y=100)
entry3.place(x=300,y=150)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если совсем просто, то убрать строку `def login2():`. То, что у вас функция находится внутри `if`, не значит, что она выполнится при выполнении условия. Функция выполнится только когда ее вызовут.

Просто вытащите код этой функции, чтобы в `if` был просто этот код, либо вытащите функцию отдельно, а в `if` вызывайте ее.

Т.е., вариант 1:

```
def login():
   api_id=(entry1.get())
   api_hash=(entry2.get())
   phone=(entry3.get())
   client = TelegramClient('Spam-session', api_id, api_hash)
   client.start()
   client.connect()
   client.flood_sleep_threshold = 0
   if not  client.is_user_authorized():
     log2 = Toplevel()
     log2.geometry('250x250')

     client.send_code_request(phone)
     client.sign_in(phone, input('Введите полученный код: '))
```

Вариант 2:

```
def login2(client, phone):
   log2 = Toplevel()
   log2.geometry('250x250')

   client.send_code_request(phone)
   client.sign_in(phone, input('Введите полученный код: '))


def login():
   api_id=(entry1.get())
   api_hash=(entry2.get())
   phone=(entry3.get())
   client = TelegramClient('Spam-session', api_id, api_hash)
   client.start()
   client.connect()
   client.flood_sleep_threshold = 0
   if not  client.is_user_authorized():
      login2(client, phone)
```

---

Пример, как вручную сделать окно запроса кода:

```
def login2(client, phone):
    log2 = Toplevel()
    log2.geometry('250x250')
    log2.title("Введите полученный код")
    entry = Entry(log2)
    entry.pack()
    
    result = None
    def on_ok():
        # При нажатии на кнопку OK записываем текст в локальную переменную result функции login2 и закрываем окно
        nonlocal result
        result = entry.get()
        log2.destroy()
    
    Button(log2, text="OK", command=on_ok).pack()
    
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    log2.wait_window()  # Ждем закрытия окна
    
    # Если что-то введено, посылаем команду
    if result:
        client.sign_in(phone, result)
```

Также можно использовать уже готовый диалог из tkinter:

```
from tkinter import simpledialog


def login2(client, phone):
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    
    result = simpledialog.askstring("Введите полученный код", "Введите полученный код")
    
    # Если что-то введено, посылаем команду
    if result:
        client.sign_in(phone, result)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь,если можно, подскажите, у меня все равно не появляется окно, а в консоль приходит запрос номера телефона я так понимаю это от 'client.send_code_request(phone)'  как возможно сделать так, что бы брало данные из 'entry' а не из консоли

Comment: @Farodin дополнил ответ

Comment: Всё равно направляет в консоль (https://prnt.sc/10n61gi) . При нажатии на кнопку приложение останавливается и ждёт ответа от консоли

Comment: @Farodin ну так уберите все `input` и замените их на `simpledialog.askstring`

Comment: Inputов  у меня не осталось(он был всего один)

Comment: @Farodin см. https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/basic/creating-a-client.html `If no phone or bot token is provided, you will be asked one through input().` При создании TelegramClient нужно передавать телефон или токен бота.

Comment: Но я же , по идее, передаю телефон, получая его из entry3. Заранее прошу прощения за свою глупость

Comment: @Farodin вы его только в client.send_code_request передаете. А нужно передавать в сам TelegramClient: `client = TelegramClient('Spam-session', api_id, api_hash, phone=phone)`

Comment: Пробовал такой способ до вашего ответа https://prnt.sc/10n76b6 вот результат

Comment: Точнее не так, нужно убрать `client.start()`, то есть брать первый вариант без start: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IJIS.png . Т.е. либо сами запрашиваете все данные у пользователя, либо вызываете start(), и все запрашивается через input.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде бы заработало

Comment: Если можно, еще немного вашей помощи

Comment: добавил блок кода который отвечает за саму отправку сообщений и получил ошибку https://prnt.sc/10nbkln

Comment: вот сам фрагмент кода https://prnt.sc/10nblcd

Comment: Значит переменная client не видна там где вы пытаетесь к ней обращаться